# AttributeError: 'Field' object has no attribute 'vocab' preventing me to run the code

Tags: nlp, torchtext

I have found this code and I wanna see what is the object that im printing in the last line. im new in field of nlp so please help me fix this code, because it gives `AttributeError: 'Field' object has no attribute 'vocab'`error. by the way I have found out that torchtext has been changed and the error is probably related to these changes, and the code probably was working before.

```
import spacy
from torchtext.legacy.data import Field
spacy_eng = spacy.load("en")
def tokenize_eng(text):
    return [tok.text for tok in spacy_eng.tokenizer(text)]

english = Field(
    tokenize=tokenize_eng, lower=True, init_token="<sos>", eos_token="<eos>"
)
print([english.vocab.stoi["<sos>"]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build the vocabulary for the `english` `Field` before you try to access it. You will need a dataset to build the vocabulary, which will be the dataset you are looking to build a model for. You can use `english.build_vocab(...)`. [Here are the docs](https://torchtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html) for `build_vocab`.

Also, if you would like to learn how to migrate what you are doing to the new version of torchtext, [here is a good resource](https://colab.research.google.com/github/pytorch/text/blob/master/examples/legacy_tutorial/migration_tutorial.ipynb).